# Chart doesn't draw lines between the dots

Tags: extjs, charts, extjs4

I have an ExtJS Chart,

The chart doesn't draw lines between the dots...

this is my config:

```
{
    title: 'Chart',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'chart',
            itemId: 'chart',
            animate: true,
            store: me.IndexStatusStore,
            axes: [
                {
                    type: 'Numeric',
                    position: 'left',
                    fields: ['docsPerSec'],
                    label: {
                        renderer: function (v) {
                            return Ext.util.Format.number(v, '0');
                        }
                    },
                    title: 'Documents per second',
                    grid: true,
                    minimum: 0
                },
                {
                    type: 'Category',
                    position: 'bottom',
                    fields: ['now'],
                    title: 'Time running',
                    //minimum: 0 start time
                    label: {
                        renderer: function (v) {
                            return Ext.util.Format.date(new Date(v), 'H:i:s');
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            series: [
                {
                    type: 'line',
                    axis: 'left',
                    xField: 'now',
                    yField: 'docsPerSec'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The chart is drawing the points correctly but the lines between them are missing. It might be worth mentioning that on an interval I update store's data, the chart updates automatically.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you share example data, or even create a fiddle?

Comment: I had the line before and in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/r3Dpq/2/) I created the line is present too.. I'll look a little further... I'm doing some funky stuff reducing my records by removing every second record from the store if the store count goes over 49 records... maybe it's that..

Comment: damn! even now it works fine in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/r3Dpq/3/) :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue... It was my data. The first record had a very high value. It seems like the chart can't handle that. The reason why this high value was present was a miscalculation in the speed and it stayed like that because I kept the first record.